# How to put info into columns in a richtextbox using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Hi I want to display three columns in a richtextbox when item in combobox is selected. I want to display that corresponding actors Year, Movie name, and amount made from movie columns. Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub employeeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles employeeComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    If employeeComboBox.SelectedItem Is "Sean Connery" Then
        historyTextBox.Text = ""
    ElseIf employeeComboBox.SelectedItem Is "George Lazenby" Then
        historyTextBox.Text = ""
    ElseIf employeeComboBox.SelectedItem Is "Roger Moore" Then
        historyTextBox.Text = ""
    ElseIf employeeComboBox.SelectedItem Is "Timothy Dalton" Then
        historyTextBox.Text = ""
    ElseIf employeeComboBox.SelectedItem Is "Pierce Brosnan" Then
        historyTextBox.Text = ""
    ElseIf employeeComboBox.SelectedItem Is "Daniel Craig" Then
        historyTextBox.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RichTextBox1.Text = "Row1 Col1" & vbTab & " Row1 Col2" & vbTab & "Row1 Col3" & vbCrLf &
  "Row2 Col1" & vbTab & " Row2 Col2" & vbTab & "Row2 Col3"
```

However, I would recommend you use a `DataGridView` control instead of a RichTextBox, so you can click on column headings to sort by name, year, etc.

```
Dim dtb As New DataTable
dtb.Columns.Add("Year", GetType(String))
dtb.Columns.Add("Film", GetType(String))
dtb.Columns.Add("Actor", GetType(String))
dtb.Rows.Add("2001", "Film one", "Zac Black")
dtb.Rows.Add("2002", "Film two", "Young Green")
dtb.Rows.Add("2003", "Film three", "Xerxes Snifflehauser")
DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
DataGridView1.DataSource = dtb
```

Comment: Well, it's more complicated than this.  Your columns will get messed up with large titles.  You must calculated the maximum width of every column based on the largest item of the column, the fill every item to have the same width.  If you use a fixed-width font, then count the number of characters, otherwise, have fun with the Graphics.MeasureString function.

Comment: No need for that - you can just set the Autosize properties?

Comment: I was talking about the RichTextBox solution... the DataGridView solution is perfect.